# How to select rows in a Grid View without using asp:BoundFields

Tags: c#, asp.net, select, gridview, datatables

In my ASP.Net app, I have a `Grid View' being populated from my SQL Server table using a stored procedure that selects data from the table based on a stored username. I first manage the stored procedures and data in a separate C# file called 'DataAccessManager.cs':

```
public class DataAccessManager
{
    private string _connString;
    private Dictionary<string, string> _questions;
    private Dictionary<string, string> _answers;

    public DataAccessManager()
    {
        _connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DevConnectionString"].ToString();
        _questions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        _answers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    // 

    public DataTable GetTicketByOwnership(string UserName)
    {
        DataTable ticketDT = null;
        SqlConnection conn = null;

        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(_connString);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.a_GetTicketByOwnership", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserName;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            ticketDT = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return ticketDT;
    }
 ....  
}
```

I then call the `GetTicketByOwnership(string UserName)` to return the datatable `ticketDT` to populate my Gridview named 'uxTicketGridView' on Page Load.

```
public partial class Summary : Page
{
    DataAccessManager _dtMgr;
    protected int _widestDataLength;
    DataTable _mainDT;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _widestDataLength = 0;
        _dtMgr = new DataAccessManager();
        Session["UserNameSession"] = "jbrown";
        Session["isUserAuthenticated"] = true;
        string staffName = _dtMgr.GetStaffNameByUser(Session["UserNameSession"].ToString());

        if (staffName == string.Empty)
        {
            //error
        }
        else
        {
            Session["StaffName"] = staffName;
            uxStaffNameTextbox.Text = "Hello " + staffName;
            _mainDT = _dtMgr.GetTicketByOwnership(Session["UserNameSession"].ToString());
 ....
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                uxTktGridView.DataSource = _mainDT;
                uxTktGridView.DataBind();
     ....
```

Back in the HTML, the `asp:GridView`is added to the DOM with a `CommandField` select button:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="uxTktGridView" runat="server" CssClass="GridView" BorderStyle="Solid" onRowDataBound="uxTktGridView_RowDataBound" OnSorting="uxTktGridView_Sorting" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#D6D2D2" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" SelectedIndex="-1" AllowSorting="True"  Font-Size="Small" Width="100%" Visible="True" EnableModelValidation="True" style=" margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
     <Columns>
         <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Details" ButtonType="Button" HeaderText="Select" />
     </Columns>
        ....
</asp:GridView>
```

My question now is 'How do I add the functionality to select the rows in my `gridview` without using `asp:BoundFields`? Is that possible? I can already select the rows when I click the buttons, but what I need is to then pull out a piece of info from that row (say the value from the 'Ticket Number' column) to use in another stored procedure like this `string ticketNumber = uxRowSelected.SelectedValue("Ticket Number");` or something similar. When I tried adding `<asp:BoundField DataField="TicketNumber" HeaderText="Ticket Number" />` , etc...column by column, I ended up with doubles of everything. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you need. But you can always use `DataKeyNames`. You define them in the GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id, name">
```

Then you can always access those values using the correct row number and DataKey.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[i].Values[0]);
    string name = GridView1.DataKeys[i].Values[1].ToString();
}
```

Comment: OK, sorry it took so long to verify that this worked, but it does indeed work. `DataKeyNames` did the trick. I was actually able to add `AutoGenerateColumns=false` to the gridview and then could use the `<asp:BoundField.../>` without getting doubles. Thanks again!